# getting an error "not defined" trying to Path(file.csv) in python

Tags: python, csv, import

I am learning to use the Path tool to import .CSV files in python. I have saved a .CSV file in the same location as the .PY file. here is my code:

from pathlib import Path

csvpath = Path(data_test.csv)

print (csvpath)

The error message is saying: "NameError: name "data_test" is not defined"

what is going on here? the .CSV and .PY files are in the same location. ??

Answer (score 0):

the path should be a string
csvpath = Path('data_test.csv')

print (csvpath)

It cant find it, because its looking for a declared variable data_test.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
csvpath = Path("data_test.csv")  # filename should be inside " "
print (csvpath)
```